# Blurb Generator

Tags: java, recursion

I have been working on a project for class and I'm about finished but I have one error at the end can anyone help? The main method is where stuck it says The method main cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type.

```
package cwcanada;
import java.util.Random;

public class blurb {

    public class RecursiveBlurb
    {

        Random chooser;

        public RecursiveBlurb()
        {
            chooser = new Random() ;
        }
        private String getWhoozitYs(){

            StringBuffer y = new StringBuffer();

            boolean stop = chooser.nextBoolean();
            if (!stop)
            y.append(getWhoozitYs());
            else
            return y.toString();

            y.append("y");
            return y.toString();
        }

        private String getWhoozit()
        {
            StringBuffer whoozit = new StringBuffer();
            whoozit.append("x");
            whoozit.append(getWhoozitYs());

            return whoozit.toString();

        }

        private String getWhatzit()
        {
            StringBuffer whatzit =new StringBuffer();
            whatzit.append("q");
            boolean z = chooser.nextBoolean();
            if (z)
            whatzit.append("z");
            else
            whatzit.append("d");

            whatzit.append(getWhoozit());

            return whatzit.toString();

        }

        private String getMultipleWhatzits()
        {
            StringBuffer whatzits =new StringBuffer();

            whatzits.append(getWhatzit());
            boolean stop = chooser.nextBoolean();
            if (!stop)
            whatzits.append(getMultipleWhatzits());
            else
            return whatzits.toString();

            return whatzits.toString();

        }

        public String generateBlurb()
        {
            StringBuffer blurb = new StringBuffer();
            blurb.append(getWhoozit());
            blurb.append(getMultipleWhatzits());

            return blurb.toString();
        }

        public static void main (String args [])
        {

            RecursiveBlurb blurbs = new RecursiveBlurb();

            System.out.println("Blurb : " + blurbs.generateBlurb());

            System.out.println("Blurb : " + blurbs.generateBlurb());

            System.out.println("Blurb : " + blurbs.generateBlurb());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the error is pretty clear.  Move the method up to the blurb class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call an instance method from inside a static main method.  You have to declare all of your methods as static, if you're going to put the main method inside the `RecursiveBlurb` class.  My suggestion would be to extract the main method to a different class, because that will make it easier to use statically.

Answer (score 0):

I regularly encounter this issue with Java, and I would hazard a guess that you have a similar issue to me.

I usually run all my Java programs like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    new MyProgram();
}

//And the code you usually have in the static main goes here:
public MyProgram(){
    //Calls to generate blurb.
}
```

Java's stringent ruling regarding `static` can often become quite a headache, so I simply use `main` as the entrance into the program, and run everything else after that as regular code - and I never run into any issues with compiler errors relating to static methods.

Edit: Also, it's very bad programming pratice to have your class name start with a lower-case letter.  Use `public class Blurb` with a capital B to adhere by Java Coding Standards.

Comment: `static` members isn't a "rule", it's a vital concept of object oriented programming...

Comment: @Qix true, I'm not debating its usage, however it's a very common issue that new programmers run into without realizing it.  My solution above is a 'quick fix' that alleviates those early errors.